# 'Dynamic' Javascript Array Name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to name an array a random number, theoretically.

```
var arrayname = "foo";

(the value of arrayname) = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Maybe you could use eval...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var dates = {};

var cdate = new Date(),
    arrayname = Math.floor(cdate.getTime()+Math.random()*16),
    arrayname = "time_"+arrayname;

dates[arrayname] = ["1", "2", "3"];

// to retrieve
console.log(dates[arrayname]);
```

You could try the `window` object. Or use an array to hold your array.

```js
var arrayname = "foo";
window[arrayname] = ["1", "2", "3"];
console.log(foo); // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: So when I tried to do 
http://pastebin.com/TS9c7BE8 and I typed the number into console, it was returning a string.

Comment: Because it leeches the variable to global scope?

Comment: @JamesA., JavaScript variables *must*  start with a character, and not a number.

Answer (score 3):

You can create object with arrays as properties. Property name could represent array name. For example:

```
var arrays = {
    foo: ["1", "2", "3"],
    other: ["4", "5"]
};


var arrayname = "foo";
console.log(arrays[arrayname]);
```